# What would happen if a wireless device cannot reach all antennas of an access point?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, antenna

Consumer wireless access points (or wireless routers) usually have more than 1 antenna. What would happen if I put 1 antenna on one side of a thick wall, and the other antenna on the other side? Does a device disconnect, or work at half the bandwidth?

I know in some wireless routers with 4 antennas, 2 are used for 2.4GHz and 2 for 5GHz. Let's put that aside for now and talk about single band ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a non-MIMO (a.k.a. 1x1:1, SISO) system, meaning the two antennas are just for diversity (main and aux, connected to the same single radio chain), then it should work fine.

If it's a 2x2:2 MIMO system, which means each antenna is connected to a separate radio chain, then it gets more complicated. Certainly no client would be able to use data rates requiring two spatial streams, so your bandwidth would be cut in half. There might be other problems depending on the AP's MIMO implementation details. For example, what if your AP always uses Antenna 1 when it needs to transmit using a single spatial stream? That would mean the network would only work on Antenna 1's side of the wall.

Even if 1SS transmissions are transmitted by both antennas simultaneously, you could have smaller problems like the AP might periodically try to see if it can get 2SS transmission through to 2SS clients, but fail of course, wasting some airtime with the failed attempts. 2SS clients may do the same thing, wasting more airtime with failed attempts.

It's kind of hard to predict without knowing proprietary internal details of the MIMO implementation you're working with.